# How can I remove all custom methods and classes from an R workspace?

Tags: r, class, r-s4

I've been experimenting a lot with S4 classes lately, and it is a pain to restart R in order to clear all class definitions and custom methods from my workspace. Obviously `rm(list=ls(all.names=TRUE))` is of no use. I could manually remove all classes and methods individually by writing lines one-by-one, but I'm sure there's got to be an easier way.

An example showcasing my problem:

```
.myClass <- setClass("myClass", representation=representation(mySlot="numeric"))
mySlot <- function(x) x@mySlot
setMethod("[", signature=c("myClass", "numeric", "missing"), function(x, i, j, ...) {
  initialize(x, mySlot=mySlot(x)[i])
})
```

Try to remove everything with `rm()`:

```
rm(list=ls(all.names=TRUE))
```

However, the class definition and custom method are still present:

```
> x <- new("myClass", mySlot=1:4)
> x[1]
Error in x[1] : could not find function "mySlot"
```

Since `mySlot()` was an object it was removed with `rm`, but the method referencing `mySlot()` remained. I'd like to know how to remove *all* classes and *all* custom methods in one fell swoop.

Comment: Classes can be removed, AFAIK, with removeClass(). However, I do not know a good way to automate it in your case. If you had a list of class names you could iterate through it and remove the classes with removeClass() though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to know what you're hoping R will remember of your session. You can

```
removeClass("myClass", where=.GlobalEnv)
removeMethods("[", where=.GlobalEnv)
```

or if you've lost track of what-all you've done the following hacks might help

```
## Class definitions are prefixed by '.__C__'
mangled <- grep(".__C__", ls(all=TRUE, envir=.GlobalEnv), value=TRUE)
classes <- sub(".__C__", "", mangled)
for (cl in classes) removeClass(cl, where=.GlobalEnv)

## Methods tables are prefixed by '.__T__'
mangled <- grep(".__T__", ls(all=TRUE, envir=.GlobalEnv), value=TRUE)
methods <- unique(sub(".__T__(.*):.*", "\\1", mangled))
for (meth in methods) removeMethods(meth, where=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: That does what I need it to do. Thanks! Basically, I wanted R to remember nothing from the session and be able to begin anew.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment but it is too long so I put it as an answer.

You can remove the definition of a class using `removeClass`. But, removing the definition of a class does not remove the methods which
are associated to it. To really remove a class, it is necessary to remove the
class then to remove all its methods using `removeMethod`.

This is painful so either you restart R or  better is to **create a custom package** where you define your class and use some tools `devtools` to load everything use something like:

```
devtools::load_all(".")
```